# construct large "matrix" in R

Tags: r, matrix

I'm trying to construct a large matrix:

```
mat <- matrix(0,ncol=700000,nrow=700000)
```

I tried on machines with a lot of RAM but they don't seem to be able to handle it.

is there another data structure I could use that is faster or less memory intensive?

I would still need the same number of rows and columns filled with 0s.

Comment: Use a sparse matrix.

Comment: For reference, `b = object.size(matrix(0L, nrow = 1000, ncol = 1000)` is the size of 1 million values in a matrix: `format(b, units = "Mb")` gives `3.8Mb`. You want 490,000 times that many values: `format(b * 490000, units = "Tb")` gives `1.8 Terabytes`. That's not going to fit in memory on most machines. But a sparse matrix basically only store the dimensions and the indexes and values for non-zero values of a matrix. It's perfect for a mostly/all-0 matrices.

Comment: Please give details on exactly what you want to do with the matrix. Perhaps show what you want to do with a small matrix (so the code runs on your computer). Be very clear with what you want the output to be.